# Google Analytics on a web farm?

Tags: iis7, asp.net-mvc, google-analytics

Is it possible to use Google Analytics on a web farm so that it collects stats on what happened on each server in the farm? eg:

- Instead of visits, show visits per server (helps us check the load
  balancer is working)
- Instead of site speed, show site speed per server (helps us see if
  any box is unexpectedly slow)
- And so on

Answer (score 2):

I would create a google account for each server. that way I would keep track of each server usage.

Comment: This seems like the logical solution - you may not have to create a separate *Google* account though (just call each server a website under the one account, that way you can view all their stats without having to change logins)

Comment: Yeah I could create new profiles in GA.  That would allow for separate reporting by server, but how would I get the overview then?  Total visits etc

Answer (score 1):

If I had 50 farms, I could create 50 accounts... or more likely I'm not going to want to maintain all those accounts and would simply want one account to manage. I believe this makes more sense, given you can simply filter your queries/reports using a secondary sorting dimension.  Simply set your secondary dimension to be `Content>Host` and then by using an advanced filter or custom segments, you can see stats for each server. This assumes each has a unique url or IP.

If all farms are redirected by a load balancer, you might need to set a custom variable to be your farm instance, in which case this would become your secondary dimension.

Not ideal, but preferable to maintaining multiple accounts.  The downside is that when you want to do some analysis on a secondary dimension, you lose that ability.

Comment: "The downside is that when you want to do some analysis on a secondary dimension, you lose that ability." - You don't lose any capabilities if you use [advanced segments](http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1041510&topic=1032940&ctx=topic) for custom variable values.

Comment: Good point.  I had the first method in my head when finishing my answer.